# WebClient DownloadFileCompleted event not being called in the last item

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I Have a large file downloader (about 3GB) full working in almost all devices I tested it. But it some devices the download bar allways gets stuck in 99% (cannot verify this, but seems that is something related with old Win 7 versions). The download works fine, and if I restart the downloader, it shows me that the download is OK, but I cannot tell my clients to restart the downloader if it gets stuck in 99%, so I will appreciate a lot some help on this.

This is the code:

```
using (_wc = new WebClient())
            {
                _wc.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                _wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                _wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(fileToDownloadLink), PathToSaveFile);
            }
```

And the event:

```
void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This box is being called every time except the last one");
    }
```

Comment: this seems a bit of a mistery on how its working you have a using code and inside it you have an async method. From my understanding your _wc should be disposing before the DownloadFilyAsync is completed since you are not awaiting it. Try awaiting that call and see if the DownloadFileCompleted work as intended

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you, I cannot await "DownloadFileAsync", this function has it's own async callbacks that are DownloadFileCompleted and DownloadProgressChanged

Comment: i see, then dont use the using statement, declare your webclient make as new one and dispose it in the Download File Completed.